# Read email contents using PHP

Tags: php, email, postfix-mta

I have configured mail server using postfix. I'm able receive email from ouside(gmail, yahoo, etc.,). 
Those email are saved in `/var/mail/Maildir/new` path.

I'm trying to read those mails using php.

```
$emailata = file_get_contents('/var/mail/Maildir/new/1543464041.Vfd01I127d6cM759489.mail');
```

Getting all data in string. How can I get details like subject, from, body etc.,

Thx.

Comment: PD of [parsing raw email in php](//stackoverflow.com/q/12896)

Comment: @mario Thx. Getting email contents but not receiving from email address.

Comment: @mario From name received. email address is in tags <mail@example.com> it's not coming.

Comment: Should I guess from the vague "not coming" that you're printing out the email address in HTML context and you're confused how browsers treat things in angle brackets?